# GetMenuItemInfo does not set fType with MIIM_TYPE

Tags: c++, winapi, ownerdrawn

I have been working with winapi just a little bit, making a project with owner draw on menus. When I called `GetMenuItemInfo`, it sets the text of the menu item, but not the fType UINT variable flags.
Currently I have declared:

```
MenuItem->fMask = MIIM_TYPE
```

And MSDN says:

```
MIIM_TYPE Retrieves or sets the fType and dwTypeData members.
```

I don't know If I got confused with the MIIM_TYPE flag.

Here is my code:

```
void SetOwnerDrawMenu(HMENU * menu)
{
MENUIF * menu_item_information;
HMENU sub_menu_ocational;

UINT uId_menuitem;
int nMenuCountItems = GetMenuItemCount(*menu);

MENUITEMINFO * MenuItem = (MENUITEMINFO*)malloc(sizeof(MENUITEMINFO));

for(int i=0;i<nMenuCountItems;i++)
{

    menu_item_information = (MENUIF*)malloc(sizeof(MENUIF));
    menu_item_information->isSeparator=false;
    menu_item_information->max_width=0;
    sub_menu_ocational = 0;
    uId_menuitem = GetMenuItemID(*menu,i);
    memset(&MenuItem,0,sizeof(MenuItem));
    MenuItem = (MENUITEMINFO*)malloc(sizeof(MENUITEMINFO));
    MenuItem->cbSize = sizeof(MenuItem);
    MenuItem->fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
    MenuItem->cch = MAX_ODM_CCH;
    MenuItem->dwTypeData = menu_item_information->szItemText;

    GetMenuItemInfo(*menu,uId_menuitem,FALSE,MenuItem);

    UINT final_flags = MF_BYPOSITION | MF_OWNERDRAW;

    if( ( MFT_SEPARATOR & MenuItem->fType ) == MFT_SEPARATOR )
    {
        final_flags |= MF_SEPARATOR;
        menu_item_information->isSeparator = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Not important stuff
    }

    sub_menu_ocational = GetSubMenu(*menu,i);

    if(sub_menu_ocational!=NULL)
    {
        ModifyMenu(*menu,i,final_flags,0,(LPCTSTR)menu_item_information);
        // We got a submenu, repeat this operation
        SetOwnerDrawMenu(&sub_menu_ocational);
    }
    else
    {
        ModifyMenu(*menu,i,final_flags,0,(LPCTSTR)menu_item_information);
    }
}
}
```

I am inserting the menus with the `InsertMenu` function:

```
InsertMenu(tid_cmenu,0,MF_BYPOSITION | MF_SEPARATOR,0,NULL);
InsertMenu(tid_cmenu,0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, TID_EXIT, "Exit");
```

Exactly, why the `GetMenuItemInfo` is not retriving the fType?

Comment: *I already tested the fType variable, it's returning null

Comment: I cannot see any checking of API return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem is not syntax or memory size errors.
It is more like 'logic' error and a silly mistake.

The `ModifyMenu` was changing all the menu items and
setting the fType of each one to NULL or setting the MF_SEPARATOR to all of the items.

That happened because the fourth argument of the `ModifyMenu` should be the ID of the menu item, I was declaring it as 0.

I changed that argument to the real ID of the menu Item using the `GetMenuItemID` return value inside the `uId_menuitem` variable and passing it to the fourth argument of `ModifyMenu`. That fixed the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you were checking the return code from `GetMenuItemInfo` you would see that it is failing. Your error is in this line:

`MenuItem->cbSize = sizeof(MenuItem);`

The `MENUITEMINFO::cbSize` member is supposed to be set to the size of a `MENUITEMINFO` structure, but you are setting it to the size of a `MENUITEMINFO*` pointer (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the platform).

Change your code to:

`MenuItem->cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);`

Also, your code is allocating `MenuItem` outside the loop, as well as once per-iteration inside the loop, so you are leaking memory.

Comment: `sizeof(*MenuItem)` would be prefereable

Comment: Hmm.. Followed the sizeof instruction and fixed the memory leak. Still not working... It's getting the text, not the fType, already checked for GetMenuItemInfo return value, it does not gives error (As msdn, if it is right it returns nonzero value, it's returning a nonzero value).

Comment: Additional data: fType is NULL when calling GetMenuItemInfo

Comment: From memory, the value of `MFT_STRING` is 0 - are you sure its not working?

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, Well, it's supposed that the fType should have MFT_SEPARATOR if the item is a MF_SEPARATOR. The `GetMenuItemInfo` it's not declaring the MFT_SEPARATOR flag inside fType on the separator item. It's weird